# Altering express session after res.render is executed

Tags: node.js, express

I am looking to **store information** generated by a post-route **in the session**, **pass it on to a get-route** (where I redirect after the post is done), **run res.render()** with that information from the session and **then clear it so the session-variable is empty for the next route** (Code block explains problem as well if this was too vague). Please keep in mind that the code below is a simplified version, my program contains a working session in which I can store and access variables.

```js
const clearSessionMessage = async (req, res, next) => {
  await res.on('finish', () => {
    let sess = req.session;
    sess.message = '';
  });
  next();
};

app.use(clearSessionMessage);

app.get('/route', (req, res) => {
  let sess = req.session;
  res.render('template', { message: sess.message });
});

app.post('/post/route' (req, res) => {
  let sess = req.session;
  sess.message = 'The message I want to pass';  
  res.redirect('/route');
});
```

Possible solutions I have tried:

- Change the 'finish' parameter in `res.on()` to: `finish`, `end` or `close`
- Force the session to save with `req.session.save(callback)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I have been able to solve my problem.
It is possible to edit the session after calling `res.render();` but if you wish to do that you have to make sure you force the session to save with `req.session.save(callback)`. This is because express will automatically save the session after a `res.render();`, edits after the render are not automatically saved!

```js
app.get('/route', (req, res) => {
  res.render('template', { message: req.session.message });
  req.session.message = undefined;
  req.session.save(err => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    };
  });
});

app.post('/post/route' (req, res) => {
  req.session.message = 'The message I want to pass';  
  res.redirect('/route');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just got bitten by this too.  Removal of 'flash' messages stored in the session was not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to save or modify the session after a `res.render` call but save a local variable before destroying the session, which is then passed to the rendered page:

```
app.get('/route', (req, res) => {
  let msg = req.session.message;
  req.session.message = undefined;
  res.render('template', { message: msg });
});

app.post('/post/route' (req, res) => {
  req.session.message = 'The message I want to pass';  
  res.redirect('/route');
});
```